# How can i validate first three characters in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

i want to validate first three characters when user inserting phone number to database

here is my controller

```
 public function checkNumber(Request $request)
{
    $number = $request->get('phone');
    $operators_codes = str_split($number, 5);


    if ($request->ajax())
    {
        if ($request->get('phone') && strlen($request->get('phone')) > 14 && $operators_codes == 077)
        {
            return ['valid' => true, 'phone' => $request->get('phone'),"left" => ["total"=> 1, "free" => 1, "paid" => 0]];
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, validate against what exactly?

Comment: i want to validate first 3 character from request.for example you trying to insert 055-22-22 but you have to insert 555 not 055

Answer (score 2):

You can use Regular Expression (RegEx) to easily achieve that.

```
<?php 
$number="786-899-677";

// Checks if $phone begins with 555
if(preg_match("/^555/",$number)>0){
    echo "Valid Phone Number!";
}else{
    echo "Invalid Phone Number!";
}
?>
```

[PCRE RegEx Pattern](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php)

```
public function checkNumber(Request $request){
    $number = $request->get('phone');
    if(preg_match("/^555/",$number)>0){
        return ['valid' => true, 'phone' => $number, "left" => ["total"=> 1, "free" => 1, "paid" => 0]];
    }else{
        return ['valid' => false, 'phone' => $number, "left" => ["total"=> 1, "free" => 1, "paid" => 0]];
    }
}
```